# IOS quartz bubble with triangle

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-2d

have some trouble getting quartz to draw the shape I want. Basically I am going for a shape like so:

[image: bubble view]

I can get the rounded bubble, but when I try to add in the triangle it goes wrong. Here is what I normally get:

[image]

Thanks for your time.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect currentFrame = self.bounds;

CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.BorderWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.BorderColor.CGColor); 
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.FillColor.CGColor);


float pad = BorderWidth + 0.5f;
float width = currentFrame.size.width - BorderWidth - 0.5f;
float height = currentFrame.size.height - BorderWidth - 0.5f;
float rounding = BorderRadius - BorderWidth;

CGContextMoveToPoint(context,pad + TriangleSize.width, pad);

//top
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       width, 
                       pad, 
                       width, 
                       height, 
                       rounding);
//right
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       width, 
                       height, 
                       round(width / 2.0f), 
                       height, 
                       rounding);
//bottom
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       TriangleSize.width + pad, 
                       height, 
                       pad, 
                       pad , 
                       rounding);

//left
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       TriangleSize.width, 
                       pad + TriangleSize.height*3, 
                       width, 
                       pad, 
                       0);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,-TriangleSize.width - pad,TriangleSize.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,pad + TriangleSize.width, pad + TriangleSize.height);

CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       pad + TriangleSize.width, 
                       pad - TriangleSize.height, 
                       width, 
                       height, 
                       rounding);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all I needed to do was post an question to figure it out. :) Anyway here is the code I used to get it working if anyone finds this later down the road:

```
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect currentFrame = self.bounds;

CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.BorderWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.BorderColor.CGColor); 
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.FillColor.CGColor);


float pad = BorderWidth + 0.5f;
float width = currentFrame.size.width - BorderWidth - 0.5f;
float height = currentFrame.size.height - BorderWidth - 0.5f;
float rounding = BorderRadius - BorderWidth;
float pos = (height/3); //height/2 //setting this to a third as I want the arrow to be a bit higher than the middle

CGContextMoveToPoint(context,pad*3 + TriangleSize.width, pad);
//top
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       width, 
                       pad, 
                       width, 
                       height, 
                       rounding);
//right
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       width, 
                       height, 
                       round(width / 2.0f), 
                       height, 
                       rounding);
//bottom
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       pad + TriangleSize.width,
                       height, 
                       pad, 
                       pad , 
                       rounding);

CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, TriangleSize.width,pos + TriangleSize.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0,pos);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, TriangleSize.width,pos - TriangleSize.height);
//left
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 
                       pad + TriangleSize.width,
                       pad,
                       width, 
                       pad, 
                       rounding);


CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

// Draw a clipping path for the fill
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,pad*3 + TriangleSize.width, pad);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, width, pad, width, height, rounding);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, width, height, round(width / 2.0f), height,rounding);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, pad + TriangleSize.width,height, pad, pad, rounding);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, TriangleSize.width,pos + TriangleSize.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0,pos);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, TriangleSize.width,pos - TriangleSize.height);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, pad + TriangleSize.width,pad,width, pad, rounding);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextClip(context);
```

Comment: What are you setting for boarderwidth, boarderradius and triangle size

Comment: see this: https://github.com/daltoniam/GPLib-iOS/blob/master/GPLib/Views/GPBubbleView.m, but I am using BorderRadius = 8; BorderWidth = 0.5; TriangleSize = CGSizeMake(8, 8);